# How to parse single vector of strings to column names/column values by pattern

Tags: r, data-science

I have a single column with separate string values like:

```
                                     strings
1 J96C75D56I96Z95W39S79H89K69Y49B99R49L49U61
2 J96C75D56I96Z95W39S79H89K69Y49B99R49L49U61
```

I want to convert it to a data frame using a pattern. For example, the first two character positions in a string are the first column's name (J9) and the 3rd position is that first column's value (6). The pattern is 2,1,2,1...

What I want is similar to the text-to-columns function in Excel. How can I do it in R?

Expected output:

```
J9 C7 5D
6  5  5  and so on..
6  5  5  and so on..
```

Comment: Click the link to get images.I have used Excel
(text to columns function ) to convert..But i want to do it in R.

Comment: Please do not provide data as images.  Provide it as text that can be read into R.  Also, explain the algorithm to go from input to output and provide the R code for what you have tried.

Comment: @user8545255 - I noticed an extra digit needs to be added onto the end of the sample string you provided. So please use the sample string I've provided when trying my solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this, but here's an intuitive way that might help teach some useful R concepts in the process:

```
x <- c("J96C75D56I96Z95W39S79H89K69Y49B99R49L49U61")

colNames <- paste0(unlist(strsplit(x, ""))[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)],
                   unlist(strsplit(x, ""))[c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)])

values <- paste0(unlist(strsplit(x, ""))[c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)])

df <- data.frame(matrix(values,nrow=1))
colnames(df) <- colNames
```

Output:

```
  J9 C7 D5 I9 Z9 W3 S7 H8 K6 Y4 B9 R4 L4 U6
1  6  5  6  6  5  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  1
```

**EDIT:**

If you have multiple strings like this that you have to merge into a data frame, here's one option:

```
df <- data.frame(strings=c("J96C75D56I96Z95W39S79H89K69Y49B99R49L49U61",
                           "J96C75D56I96Z95W39S79H89K69Y49B99R49L49U61"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colNames <- paste0(unlist(strsplit(df[1,], ""))[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)],
                   unlist(strsplit(df[1,], ""))[c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)])

x <- lapply(df$strings,
            function(i) matrix(paste0(unlist(strsplit(i,""))[c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)]),nrow=1))

require(plyr)
df <- data.frame(rbind.fill.matrix(x))
colnames(df) <- colNames
```

Output:

```
  J9 C7 D5 I9 Z9 W3 S7 H8 K6 Y4 B9 R4 L4 U6
1  6  5  6  6  5  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  1
2  6  5  6  6  5  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  1
```

Comment: Thank youu ,it answered my Question. And,what if i have like 20 lakh observations(number of rows).Do i  follow the same procedure or is there any better way.

Comment: @user8545255 - You're welcome. See the edit above for use with multiple strings.

Comment: @user8545255 - Please remember to select the check mark next to this answer to help the community know it's been solved and to help others with the same question find their answer even faster.

Comment: Hey when i tried with my data ,i am getting an error like "Error in strsplit(dctxdat2weeks[1, ], "") : non-character argument"  . in the second step while using PASTE function

Comment: @user8545255 - That's alright. It's an easy fix. Just make sure your data is of class character and not a factor class. One way to do this is by reading in your data with the option "stringsAsFactors = FALSE". Another way is to manually change your data like this df$strings <- as.character(df$strings).

Answer (score 0):

if your rows are the same length (common thing in .txt files) you may try with a fixed width format:

```
read.fwf()
```

something like

```
read.fwf(yourfile.txt, widths=c(2,1,2,1), colnames=c(variable1,value1,variable2,value2))
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Can you provide some sample data to test it?

Comment: `rio_frio <- read.fwf("http://smn.conagua.gob.mx/tools/RESOURCES/Diarios/15082.txt", widths=c(12, 6, 7, 7, 4), skip=21)` (in this case you have to delete the last row) `rio_frio <- rio_frio[-dim(rio_frio)[1],]` and then `colnames(rio_frio) <- c("date","precipitation","evaporation","tmax","tmin")`